# Override a static resource in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, resources, staticresource

I want to override a `StaticResource` that is configured in a resource dictionary of a different assembly in my own resource dictionary. I tried to configure a new resource with the same key, with no success. The resource that actually gets loaded comes from the resource dictionary of the mentioned assembly.

For demonstration purposes, I'll call the resource "MyResource":

**MyResourceDictionary.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns=...>
    <!-- I use the same key as the original resource, from the other assembly -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyResource">
        <!--My own implementation of that resource -->
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class=...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- Resource dictionary from different assembly -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Assembly;component/ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
                <!-- My resource dictionary -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApplication;component/ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```