# Change mouseover colour of all controls globally WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Buttons, column headers, comboboxes etc. all go a nice Microsoft blue when you mouseover them.

I'd much rather they went a nice shade of my corporate green.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any way to change this colour either globally for my application or by window.

Failing that, will I have to change this for each individual control type?

Comment: This seems more like a windows settings question than a programming question. Or are you wanting to impose your preferred color scheme on your users?

Comment: You could create styles for all the generic controls such as button,combobox etc in app.xaml, and don't give a  resource key (x:Key), then all controls in your application would pick up this style.

Comment: @RufusL I'm trying to impose this on my users...

Comment: Check this out: [WPF Tutorial.net - Behaviors](https://www.wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have to define a `Style` for each control. This is because the visuals and visual states are defined by the internal `ControlTemplate` of each control.

But you can significantly reduce the amount of work by reusing templates and cascading styles.

To allow easy color theming and centralized customization, you should create a resource that defines all relevant colors of your theme:

**ColorResources.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary>

  <!-- Colors -->
  <Color x:Key="HighlightColor">DarkOrange</Color>
  <Color x:Key="DefaultControlColor">LightSeaGreen</Color>
  <Color x:Key="ControlDisabledTextColor">Gray</Color>
  <Color x:Key="BorderColor">DarkGray</Color>
  <Color x:Key="MouseOverColor">LightSteelBlue</Color>

  <!-- Brushes -->
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightBrush" Color="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlDisabledTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource ControlDisabledColor}" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource BorderColor}" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MouseOverBrush" Color="{StaticResource MouseOverColor}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

You may add the following styles an templates to the *App.xaml* file:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/File/Path/To/ColorResources.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

      ...
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

To override the color of the selected row in a `GridView` or `DataGrid` you simply need to override the default brush `SystemColors.HighlightBrush` used by these controls:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                 Color="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" />
```

To override the default color of controls like the column headers of  e.g `DatGrid` you simply need to override the default brush `SystemColors.ControlBrush` used by these controls:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
                 Color="{StaticResource DefaultControlColor}" />
```

For simple `ContentControls` like `Button` or `ListBoxItem` you can share a common `ControlTemplate`. This shared `ControlTemplate` will harmonize the visual states:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BaseContentControlTemplate" 
                 TargetType="ContentControl">
  <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <ContentPresenter/>
  </Border>

  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ControlDisabledTextBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This base template will be applied using base styles. This allows simple chaining (style inheritance) and reuse of the `BaseContentControlTemplate` for different controls like `Button` or `ListBoxItem`:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseContentControlStyle" 
       TargetType="ContentControl">
  <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource BaseContentControlTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Some `ContentControl` like a `Button` might need additional states like `Pressed`. You can extend additional basic visual states by creating a base style that e.g., targets `ButtonBase` and can be used with any control that derives from `ButtonBase`:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseButtonStyle" 
       TargetType="ButtonBase" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentControlStyle}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

To apply this base styles you have to target the controls explicitly. You use this styles to add more specific visual states or layout e.g., `ListBoxItem.IsSelcted`, `ToggleButton.IsChecked` or `DataGridColumnHeader`:

```
<!-- Buttons -->
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}" />

<Style TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!- ListBox -->
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentControlStyle}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!-- ListView -->
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}" />

<!-- 
  GridView 
  Since GridViewColumnHeader is also a ButtonBase we can extend existing style 
-->
<Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}" />

<Style x:Key="BaseGridViewStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!-- 
  DataGrid
  Since DataGridColumnHeader is also a ButtonBase we can extend existing style 
-->
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}">
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrush}" />
</Style>
```

Other more complex composed controls like `ComboBox`, `TreeView` or `MenuItem` require to override the control's template individually. Since these controls are composed of other controls, you usually have to override the styles for this controls too. E.g., `ComboBox` is composed of a `TextBox`, `ToggleButton` an `Popup`.
You can find their styles at [Microsoft Docs: Control Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates).

This is a very simple and basic way to add theming to your application. Knowledge of the inheritance tree of the controls helps to create reusable base styles. Reusing styles helps to reduce the effort to target and customize each control.
Having all visual resources like colors or icons defined in one place makes it easy to modify them without having to know/modify each control individually.

Comment: Could you please provide some clarity as to how you override the default brush for a `GridView`? I've tried using your snippet but I'm not sure where to place it.

Comment: You can add everything to _App.xaml_. Otherwise create a new XAML file e.g. _ColorResources.xaml_ that contains a `ResourceDictionary`. Then add all color definitions to it and merge it into the `ResourceDictionary` of _App.xaml_. If this doesn't help then what exactly is your issue? Have you defined colors inside a dedicated file and don't know how to merge it?

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify... I've added the resources to my resource dictionary, that's fine enough, I know how to do that. I mean where/how do I override the default brush

Comment: Thank you. I see. Which brush exactly do you mean? You should create a `Style` that targets `GridView` and set the brushes from there. Selected cell or row brush should be covered by overriding the `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` like in the example.

Comment: Ahh right, so you just add the style to the resource dictionary?

Comment: I mean if  `GrdiViewColumn` is defined by a template and you wish to override e.g. BorderBrush, then you should style the content e.g. `TextBlock`. But in general if you wish just to override the select cell or selected row color then overriding `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` will do it: `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />`. See example above.

Comment: Then add every resource to _App.xaml_ or to a dedicated file, which you then merge into _App.xaml_ using `MergedDictionary` (see my example). You can post your code, maybe I can help you.

Comment: Just iun case I confused you, I meant you can override `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` directly in _App.xaml_. This should not go into a `Style`. But note that overriding this brush also affects e.g. `DatGrid`.

Comment: Ok, I have reviewed your question. It seems I was too fast, sorry. It's the `GrdiView` which is a special templating of a simple `ListViewItem`. So overriding `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` won't get you far. You need a `Style` that targets `ListViewItem`. The item style I have provided in my example won't work as it would override the template of the `GridViewColumn`. When using a `GridView` it's the `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate` that visualizes the cell content or `ListViewItem.Content`. You cant target `GridViewColumn` directly as it dosn't derive from `Frameworkelement`.

Comment: So to just override the selcetion color create a special named `Style` for `ListView` that uses a `GridView`.  This should not define any template. If you wish to use a more finegrained design of the cells you would have to create a (reusable) `DataTemplate` and set the `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate` of each column explicitly. To override the column headers create a style that targets `GridViewColumnHeader` and extends a style that targets `ButtonBase`. I have added the corresponding styles to my answer (bottom). I have added comment sections to group the styles according to their target.

Comment: I hope this helps. Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. I also thought you were using a `DataGrid` in your example and not a `GridView`. Add all styles to _App.xaml_. Does this help?

Comment: The `BaseGridViewStyle` (from my example) must be applied explicitly to `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` property to take effect (but only in case the `ListView` uses a `GridView`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the default styles (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates), you will find out, that each style uses `static resources` for declaring the colors. 
So to achieve your project you would have to overwrite these `static resources` where the colors are stored.

Unfortunately, this is not possible in `WPF` (was already asked before: [Override a static resource in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502580/override-a-static-resource-in-wpf)).

So your only solution would be to write a separate `Style` for each control and to re-declare the colors.